# Como criar e popular uma tabela usando jquery e banco de dados?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

Estou precisando criar uma tabela no HTML que, popule as linhas e colunas com os dados vindos de uma tabela específica do meu banco de dados. Mas quero que sempre que um novo dado seja inserido nessa tabela do banco, automaticamente apareça para o usuário na tabela HTML. Isso tudo sem fazer todo o carregamento da página novamente.

Já estou usando no meu projeto Java, JavaScript, jQuery e HTML. Há alguma forma de fazer isso com jQuery? Se não, qualquer ideia que atenda essa necessidade será bem vinda.

Comment: Ola, se bem entendi já existe a pagina criada. O que pretende é usar ajax (que pode fazer com jquery) que atualize a tabela. Compreendi bem?

Comment: Um amigo resolveu o problema aqui no trabalho um pouco antes de mim. Ele fez com javascript e json, minha solução ficou com o angular e json. Todas as duas atenderam a necessidade. Resolvi usar a solução do cara aqui por questões de deixar o projeto mais limpo, pois já uso na aplicação o javascript, obtei por nao usar o angular apesar de ser uma solução mais completa.

Comment: Ola, post por favor a solução e marque como certo. Assim fica respondido e pode ajudar outros que tenham a mesma questão.

Comment: Assim que possivel vou estar postando. Obrigado.

Comment: Se você resolveu o seu problema, seria interessante você responder a sua pergunta, para porteriormente pessoas com o mesmo problema poderem ter uma solução.

Answer (score 1):

Bom pelo que você descreve exergo 2 passos que são necessários.

- Acredito que uma solução seria você fazer um serviço para receber as informações dado que se trata de um banco de dados, assim o método retornaria esses dados e você apenas faria o Javascript com o jQuery consumir o serviço.
- Sobre a atualização dos campos, bom você precisa utilizar um padrão que se não me falha a memória é o OBSERVER. De x em x tempo ele consulta o método e altera se tiver conteúdo.

Achei esse exemplo no stackoverflow em inglês: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629642/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-when-a-database-is-updated

Espero ter ajudado